# how can i check if all the elements of list are integers in r?

Tags: r

Let's say I have this list:

```
List_example <- list('short'= 10,'medium'= 20,'long'=200)
```

How do I check can I check if short, medium and long are integers in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
> all(sapply(List_example, `%%`, 1) == 0)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sapply` :

```
List_example <- list('short'= 10,'medium'= 20,'long'=200)
all(sapply(List_example, is.numeric))
#[1] TRUE
```

To check for integers specifically use `is.integer`.

Comment: Be aware that these functions test for the type. So `is.integer(0.5 * 2)` is `FALSE` even though you might would like it to be `TRUE` and `is.numeric` tests basically whether the the type will behave like any number, so `is.numeric(0.5)` will be `TRUE` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If an object has an R integer type then clearly it is a whole number or if it has a double type then we can check if it equals itself rounded.

```
is_int <- function(x) is.integer(x) || (is.numeric(x) && identical(round(x), x))
all(sapply(List_example, is_int))
## [1] TRUE

L <- list(3, 5L, "xyz")
all(sapply(L, is_int))
## [1] FALSE
```

If what you mean is that you want to find out if they all have R integer type then we have the following since the numbers in the example are all doubles.

```
all(sapply(List_example, is.integer))
## [1] FALSE
```